# How to tell the NPC what hand it has?

Tags: playing-cards, vbscript

Posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710039/vbscript-poker-game-what-hand-do-i-have).

Here is the full code:

```
'buy a blank deck of cards

'declare variables
dim defaultDeck(51)
dim trueDeck(51)
dim isUsed(51)
numPlayers = 1
numCards = 12
intMyHand = 0 '0 through numPlayers-1... highest number is dealer
Set objStdOut = WScript.StdOut


'put values on the blank cards:

i=0
for suit=0 to 3
    for faceValue=0 to 12
        select case suit
            Case 0
                strSuit = chr(3)
            case 1
                strSuit = chr(4)
            case 2
                strSuit = chr(5)
            case 3
                strSuit = chr(6)
            case else
                strSuit = "SuitNotFound"
        end Select
        face = faceValue+1
        select case face
            case 11
                face = "J"      
            case 12
                face = "Q"
            case 13
                face = "K"
            case 1
                face = "A"
            case default
                face=face
        end select      
            defaultDeck(i) = face & strSuit
            i = i+1

    next
Next


function translateCard(number)

    translateCard = defaultDeck(number)

end function



'shuffle the deck

function randNum()
    max = 51
    min = 0
    Randomize
    randNum = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)

end Function


function shuffleDeck()

    'reset from last shuffle
    y=0
    for i=0 to 51
        isUsed(i) ="n"
    next

    'draw a card and put it in the deck
    do while y<52
        card = randNum()
        if isUsed(card) <> "Y" then
            isUsed(card) = "Y"
            trueDeck(y) = card
            y = y+1
        end if
    loop
'   objStdOut.Write "Shuffling."
'   jsleep(1)
'   objStdOut.Write "."
'   jsleep(1)
'   objStdOut.Write "."
'   jsleep(1)
'   objStdOut.Write "."
'   jsleep(1)
'   objStdOut.Write "Shuffled."
    objStdOut.WriteBlankLines(1)    
    jsleep(1)
end Function

function showDeck()
    for i=0 to 50
        'wscript.echo i & ". " & truedeck(i)    

        strDeck = strDeck & translateCard(truedeck(i)) & ","
    next
    strDeck = strDeck & translateCard(trueDeck(51)) 'to get rid of last comma

    wscript.echo ""
    wscript.echo "Shuffled Deck"
    wscript.echo "-------------"
    wscript.echo strDeck
end Function





function showdefDeck()
    for i=0 to 51
        wscript.echo i & ". " & defaultdeck(i)  

    '   strDeck = strDeck & truedeck(i) & ", "
    next
    'strDeck = strDeck & trueDeck(51) 'to get rid of last comma


'   wscript.echo strDeck
end Function





playa = numPlayers-1
carda = numCards-1


Dim hands()
ReDim Hands(playa,carda)
dim myHand()
reDim myHand(carda)

function Dealcards()
    totalNumCards = (numPlayers * numCards)
    tnc =0
    i = 0
    do while tnc < totalnumCards
        for c=0 to (numCards - 1)
            for p=0 to (numPlayers -1)

                Hands(p,c) = trueDeck(i)

                'debug line
                'wscript.echo truedeck(i) & " dealt to player " & p+1 & "."


                i=i+1
                tnc = tnc+1
            next
        next

    loop

'   objStdOut.Write "Dealing."
'   jsleep(1)
'   objStdOut.Write "."
'   jsleep(1)
'   objStdOut.Write "."
'   jsleep(1)
'   objStdOut.Write "Dealt."
    objStdOut.WriteBlankLines(2)
    jsleep(1)

End function

function showHand(h)
    if (h = intMyHand) then
        specialString = "*(You)* "
    else
        specialString = ""
    end if

    wscript.echo specialString & "Player " & h+1 & "'s hand:"


    for i=0 to (numCards - 1)
        theCard = translatecard(Hands(h, i))
        wscript.echo theCard
    next
    wscript.echo ""
end Function


function showSortedHand(t)

    if (t = intMyHand) then
        specialString = "*(You)* "
    else
        specialString = ""
    end if

    wscript.echo specialString & "Player " & t+1 & "'s hand:"


    theSortedHand = getHand(t)

    for each card in theSortedHand
        transCard = translateCard(card)
        wscript.echo transCard
    next


end Function





function showMyHand()
    showHand(intMyHand)
end Function


function showAllHands()
    for q=0 to playa
        showHand(q)
    next
end Function





function jsleep (seconds)

    wscript.sleep seconds*1000
end function







'sort method

function SortArray(arrShort)
    dim i, j, temp
    for i = UBound(arrShort) - 1 To 0 Step -1
        for j= 0 to i
            if arrShort(j)>arrShort(j+1) then
                temp=arrShort(j+1)
                arrShort(j+1)=arrShort(j)
                arrShort(j)=temp
            end if
        next
    next
    SortArray = arrShort
end function 



function getHand(x)
    purple = numCards-1

    dim a()
    redim a(purple)

    for i=0 to (numCards-1)
        a(i) = Hands(x, i)
    next

    sortArray a

    getHand = a

end function













objstdOUt.Write "Welcome to PokerGame1.0"

objStdOut.WriteBlankLines(1)
objStdOut.Write "-----------------------"
objStdOut.WriteBlankLines(2)



'showdefdeck

shuffleDeck
showdeck

dealCards

'showMyHand
showAllHands



showSortedHand(0)
```

Comment: As fun as this was, I'm switching to Python.

Comment: please post the Python code here when you have it working.  I will take a look at this and maybe add a tag or two to get some more attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating your cards with a nested `For` loop; one over `suit`, another over `faceValue` - I'd do the same (or quite similar). However I'm not buying the `Select Case` part:

```
for suit=0 to 3
    for faceValue=0 to 12
        select case suit
            Case 0
                strSuit = chr(3)
            case 1
                strSuit = chr(4)
            case 2
                strSuit = chr(5)
            case 3
                strSuit = chr(6)
            case else
                strSuit = "SuitNotFound"
        end Select
    ...
```

This whole `select case suit` could be replaced with `strSuit = chr(suit + 3)` with a comment that says something like `'chr(3)-chr(6): ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠`. The `"SuitNotFound"` case is a WTF for me.

Naming-wise, I don't understand how you can name a variable `suit` (good), another `faceValue` (good) and then have horrible Hungarian notation with `strSuit` - call it `currentSuit` or `cardSuit` or whatever, but **please** don't prefix with an abbreviation of type's name! [and that's valid for [python](/questions/tagged/python) as well I guess!]

Your Ace is worth 1; if you're playing Poker the Ace can be either 1 or 14, depending on the hand.

Lastly, in VBScript/VBA/VB6, you should always use the zero-footprint `vbNullString` language constant instead of `""` which takes up unnecessary memory (not that memory would be an issue though).

Comment: True, the OP seems to have no particular naming convention for variables. I particularly like `purple` which temporarily stores a number.

Comment: If you could think of a better color to store numbers, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@retailcoder's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37185/14909) good feedback, here are a few points:

1. [Option Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484(v=vs.84).aspx) as your first line is considered a best practice for VBScript. It will require you to declare all of your variables, which will assure you don't accidentally use `purpel` when you meant `purple`
2. In general your names are inconsistent or simply odd. `playa` = `numPlayers - 1` - weird, `jsleep` What's the `j`?, and `purple` - fun but meaningless.
3. Your shuffledeck method is a potential issue. In the extremely unlikely case your do loop would seemlingly hang due to repeatedly returning the same random number as `isUsed(card) <> "Y"` would keep being false.
   Something like populating trueDeck the same as defaultDeck then looping through swaping indexes might suit. Here's an example of what I mean:

   ```
   'set up trueDeck prior to this
   for i= 0 to 51
     card = randNum()
     temp = trueDeck(card)
     trueDeck(card) = i
     trueDeck(i) = temp
   loop
   ```